# Fetch data from extern HTML Table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get data from a table in an EXTERNAL HTML file (on a different server) and store the data.

Is it possible to import a html file from a http URL to work with the data?

How can I read different rows and cols from external files?

I need to get the data, store it somehow (maybe JSON or an array?) so I can work with the data.

For Example:

```
  <table id="table1" class="tg">
    <tr>
      <th>1A</th>
      <th>1B</th>
      <th>1C</th>
      <th>1D</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2A</td>
      <td>2B</td>
      <td>2C</td>
      <td>2D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3A</td>
      <td>3B</td>
      <td>3C</td>
      <td>3D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4A</td>
      <td>4B</td>
      <td>4C</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>5B</td>
        <td>5C</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>6B</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
  </table>
```

I Need to store the different colums like: 
(1A,2A,3A,4A,)
(1B,2B,3B,4B,5B,6B)
(1C,2C,3C,4C)
(1D,2D,3D)

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Sounds like you want to do web scraping. Have you considered [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)?

Comment: 1) yes, as long as you don't have a CORS issue 2) using DOMParser 3) store it however you want

Comment: You should look into jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function